# Ritchey carbon MTB fork dropout wear

Tags: fork, carbon, dropouts

I was inspecting my carbon fork dropouts and I noticed the deformation of the edge on the outer side of the right dropout that makes me unhappy. I don't know what is the reason of this issue. Here are the photos:

[image]

[image]

Maybe the diameter of the nut is too little and the pressure is higher than on other three surfaces?
How to eliminate the further growth of this issue?

Comment: Looks well used, but not dangerous to me.  Are you closing the QR too loose, allowing movement ?

Comment: It is quite normal that the quick release 'bites' into the dropout.

Comment: @Criggie very probably you are right, because I was not closing QRs  tightly enough as ParkTool suggests for example http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/tire-and-tube-removal-and-installation#article-section-9

Comment: @YuryRudakou You should post an answer to this question with all the info you've learned, and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may not be closing your Quick Releases quite tight enough, and they are causing the wear.  Here's a Park Tool blog post about it:

[Wheel installation](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/tire-and-tube-removal-and-installation#article-section-9)

Comment: I mentioned this link in my comment to original question more than one year ago. Actually, improper QR tension was the reason of the wear.

Comment: Yeah, sorry  to piggy-back on that, I was going through "unanswered" questions, looking to clear some old ones out.

Comment: If you answer your own question, its nice if you write an answer and accept it so that it doesnt show up on the front page periodically and people know something that might work if they have the same problem.